Rescanning Objects in Unity AR
I have a Unity AR script that scans for images and then makes overlays appear on top of the detected image. When I added a 10-second delay before the overlay gets destroyed overlays stopped appearing if the same image was detected again.
I had to remove a line of code from the eventArgs.updated loop:
_instantiatedPrefabs[trackedImage.referenceImage.name].SetActive(trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking);
so that the delay would occur and the overlays wouldn't disappear immediately.
I am a high school student, so sorry if this seems like a dumb question.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ARTrackedImageManager))]
public class PlaceTrackedImages : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference to AR tracked image manager component 
    private ARTrackedImageManager _trackedImagesManager;
    // List of prefabs to instaniate
    public GameObject[] ArPrefabs;
    // Dictionary array of created prefabs 
    private readonly Dictionary<string, GameObject> _instantiatedPrefabs = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    // Do not immeditaly destory parent object when it is no longer detected 
    public bool destroyOnRemoval = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Cache a reference to the Tracked Image Manager component  
        _trackedImagesManager = GetComponent<ARTrackedImageManager>();
    }
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Attach event handler when tracked images change 
        _trackedImagesManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnTrackedImagesChanged;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Remove event handler 
        _trackedImagesManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnTrackedImagesChanged;
    }

    // Event Handler 
    private void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Loop through all new tracked images that have been detected 
        foreach (var trackedImage in eventArgs.added)
        {
            // Get the name of the reference image 
            var imageName = trackedImage.referenceImage.name;
            // Loop over the array of prefabs 
            foreach (var curPrefab in ArPrefabs)
            {
                // Check whether this prefab matches the tracked image name, and that the prefab hasn't already been created 
                if (string.Compare(curPrefab.name, imageName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 && !_instantiatedPrefabs.ContainsKey(imageName))
                {
                    // Instantiate the prefab, parenting it to the ARTrackedImage 
                    var newPrefab = Instantiate(curPrefab, trackedImage.transform);
                    // Add the created prefab to the array 
                    _instantiatedPrefabs[imageName] = newPrefab;
                }
            }
        }

        // For all prefabs that have been created so far, set them active or not depending on wether their corresponding image is currently being tracked 
        foreach (var trackedImage in eventArgs.updated)
        {
            if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Limited || trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.None)
            {
                Destroy(trackedImage.gameObject, 10f);
            } 
        }

    }
}

Thanks!

The issue you're facing is likely related to how you handle the destruction of overlays with the 10-second delay. When an image is detected again, the overlay isn't appearing because the previous overlay is still being destroyed. To fix this, you can modify your code to cancel the destruction of the previous overlay if the same image is detected again.
